# How to get the sum of field 'discount' in crystal report

Tags: crystal-reports

I am doing a crystal report.. In which there is a field Discount I am not getting the sum of that field while right click->Summery->Sum. I am getting other field like OrderAmount... In crystal report all data  are coming.But not getting the sum for Discount.It is just showing the count of rows as Discount. Pls help...

Comment: Can you describe what data format the discount field is in? Could it be that it's accidentally a text field, being formatted on the database side?

Answer (score 1):

Try using formula section of Crystal Report. Create a formula for finding the sum. Use the formula in place of Summary.

 It might be look like
Formula=Sum(val({ReportField}). Change the Crystal Syntax to BasicSyntax from dropdownbox on top.